# Difference between versions of WolframScript

Tags: scripting, system, installation

On my computer (Windows 10) I currently have installed **4** instances of `wolframscript.exe`. They represent different versions of WolframScript program and each file is different. The last one comes from the independent installer for [WolframScript](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) and other came bundled with other products.

- C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0  (version 1.2.0)
- C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1  (version 1.0.1)
- C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Engine\12.0 (version 1.3.0)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript  (version 1.3.0)

What is the difference between versions of WolframScript? (There is no release history / ChangeLog for it, I think.) Which one is "the recommended" one? How can I know/choose which one is called when I run `.wls` scripts from command prompt?

Comment: Just my guess,since I have used it for a long time(for fun :P): first question: it's mmascript without notebook. Just the back-end. second: It depends on your PATH. The one your system find will execute the .wls file. For me, I have mma12.1 and 11.3 on my PC.